# Ruby 'Capitalize!' paradox

Tags: ruby

In Ruby we have the 'bang' method `capitalize!` which has the strange behavior of returning a `nil` if no changes to the string were made.

That means I can't chain this commands with other since it effectively destroys the chain if it returns `nil`.

What im trying to do is something like this:

```
fname =  fullname[0...fullname.index(' ')].capitalize!
```

which extracts the first name from a string and should capitalize it as well. But if it is already capitalized the string stored in `fname` is `nil`.

Of courses I can add another statement but was wondering if there is a way to do this "without breaking the chain".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [.capitalize](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000810) (without the bang) -- unless you actually need it to change the source.

Comment: omg... i cant believe i didn't realize this myself :(  tnx dude

Comment: Very glad to hear it helped. :)

Comment: @HanClinto What if you need the variable to capitalize and save (via !) but can not guarantee the user will input in lowercase?  Is there a way to do this without chaining another method?

Answer (score 7):

Since your statement doesn't change the value of fullname, just do:

```
fname =  fullname[0...fullname.index(' ')].capitalize
```

Which doesn't return nil if no change is made.